# Is this the correct derivative for ${a(x)}^{b(x)}$?

Tags: derivatives

I am trying to find the derivative of ${a(x)}^{b(x)}$ with respect to $x$ and I think I have a quite reasonable answer; is this correct?

$$ f(x) = {a(x)}^{b(x)} = e^{ln(a(x)) \cdot b(x)} = e^{f_{1}(x)} $$
$$ f_{1}(x) = f_{2}(x) \cdot b(x) $$
$$ f_{2}(x) = ln(a(x)) $$
$$ \frac{df_{2}}{dx}(x) = ln'(a(x)) \cdot a'(x) $$
$$ \frac{df_{1}}{dx}(x) = ln(a(x)) \cdot b'(x) + b(x) \cdot ln'(a(x)) \cdot a'(x) $$
$$ \frac{df}{dx}(x) = e^{ln(a(x)) \cdot b(x)} \cdot ({ln(a(x)) \cdot b'(x) + b(x) \cdot ln'(a(x)) \cdot a'(x)}) $$
$$ \frac{df}{dx}(x) = {a(x)}^{b(x)} \cdot ({ln(a(x)) \cdot b'(x) + b(x) \cdot ln'(a(x)) \cdot a'(x)}) $$

Comment: Yes, although to be precise $\ln'(a(x))=\frac{1}{a(x)}$

Comment: @b00nheT Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are correct. But like b00n heT notes in the comments, $\frac{d}{dx}\ln(x)=\frac1x$, so we should write that in instead. The formula you would get is
$$ \frac{d}{dx}a(x)^{b(x)}=\left( b'(x)\log a(x)+\frac{b(x)a'(x)}{a(x)} \right)a(x)^{b(x)}. $$
Although this formula is very general, perhaps I should warn you to never memorise it; it is almost always easier to just remember the chain and product rules and apply them to every individual case of $a(x)$ and $b(x)$, instead of trying to remember this monstrous formula to plug into.